# Why does $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(a_1+\sum a_k(z_n-z_0)^{k-1}\right)=a_1$

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I couldn't understand the red boxed portion i.e. why does $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_1+\sum a_k(z_n-z_0)^{k-1})=a_1$$
Please Help!

Comment: When $n\to \infty$, $z_n \to z$.

Comment: Why does the limit get carried within the power series. Is their any such theorem?

Comment: Power series give continuous functions in their region of convergence. So with $g(z) = a_1 + \sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty a_k(z-z_0)^{k-1}$, we have $\lim\limits_{z\to z_0} g(z) = g(z_0) = a_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a self-contained proof of
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k>1} a_k(z_n-z_0)^{k-1}=0 \tag{1}$$
Let $R$ be the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{k>1} a_k(z-z_0)^{k-1}$. Then the series converges when $z=z_0+R/2$. In particular, its terms are bounded when $z=z_0+R/2$. Write this out:

> there exists $M$ such that $|a_k| (R/2)^{k-1}\le M$ for all $k>1$.

When $|z-z_0|<R/2$, we have 
$$\left|\sum_{k>1} a_k(z-z_0)^{k-1}\right| \le M \sum_{k>1} \left(\frac{|z-z_0|}{R/2}\right)^{k-1} =  M \frac{|z-z_0|}{R/2} \left(1-\frac{|z-z_0|}{R/2}\right)^{-1}$$
using the formula for the sum of geometric series. The right-hand side tends to $0$ as $z\to z_0$. $\quad \Box$

---

As an aside, I would rather prove the theorem by contrapositive:

1. Assume that there is some nonzero coefficient. Let $k$ be the smallest $k$ for which $a_k\ne 0$.
2. Write $f(z)=a_k(z-z_0)^k\left(1+\sum_{j>k} \frac{a_j}{a_k}(z-z_0)^{j-k}\right)$
3. Note that $1+\sum_{j>k} \frac{a_j}{a_k}(z-z_0)^{j-k} \to 1 $ as $z\to z_0$. (This requires the kind of argument I gave above, or a reference to the continuity of power series).
4. Conclude that there is a neighborhood $N$ of $z_0$ in which $1+\sum_{j>k} \frac{a_j}{a_k}(z-z_0)^{j-k} \ne 0$.
5. Conclude that $f\ne 0$ in $N\setminus \{z_0\}$.